# How to create subquery (MySql) in laravel5?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, subquery

Here is the query in the database.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE priceid IN ( SELECT priceid
                              FROM items)
```

i need this in laravel5... thy

Comment: on this format object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ask the question better. I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
DB::select(DB::raw(
     "SELECT * FROM users
      WHERE priceid IN ( SELECT priceid FROM items)
     ")
);
```

You can also use a join as below:

```
User::join('items', 'items.priceid', '=', 'users.priceid')->get();
```

Comment: this return array i need "object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)"